# Add Pass phrase to environment variables (bashrc) in order to be used when restarting Apache server

Tags: bash, apache, ubuntu, ssl, passphrase

Currently I'm using ***"SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/path/to/pass-phrase.sh"*** on the ***/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf*** file

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "mypassphrase"
```

Everything works fine when I restart or start my apache server.

I tried to add my passphrase to my **.bashrc** like so `export SSL_PASSPHRASE=mypassphrase`

and sourced the .bashrc file `source ~/.bashrc`

After that I changed the pass-phrase.sh to

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $SSL_PASSPHRASE
```

executing `./path/to/pass-phrase.sh` result to ***mypassphrase***

but when I try to restart my Apache server, an error occur related to the passphrase

```
> [Mon Dec 16 22:56:59.611824 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] AH02580:
> Init: Pass phrase incorrect for key mysub.myinstance.com:443:0 [Mon Dec
> 16 22:56:59.611883 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library Error:
> error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag [Mon
> Dec 16 22:56:59.611892 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library
> Error: error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error [Mon Dec 16
> 22:56:59.611898 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library Error:
> error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag [Mon
> Dec 16 22:56:59.611905 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library
> Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error (Type=RSAPrivateKey)
> [Mon Dec 16 22:56:59.611912 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library
> Error: error:04093004:rsa routines:old_rsa_priv_decode:RSA lib [Mon
> Dec 16 22:56:59.611937 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library
> Error: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
> [Mon Dec 16 22:56:59.611947 2019] [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] SSL Library
> Error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding
> routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error
> (Type=PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO) [Mon Dec 16 22:56:59.613065 2019]
> [ssl:emerg] [pid 19314] AH02564: Failed to configure encrypted (?)
> private key mysub.myinstance.com:443:0, check
> /etc/apache2/ssl/mykey.key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.bashrc` configures your environment.

Apache is sometimes configured with a `sudo` to bind ports lower than 1024.  And you probably have `User` and `Group` directives that define which user Apache will switch to once started.

All this to say that your Apache runs in a different environment than your user.  It does not have access to the variables.

The "right" place to put such variables is in `$APACHE_ROOT/bin/envvars`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,

I Changed the location of the variable to `$APACHE_ROOT/bin/envvars` as you said, but I'am facing the same problem and the same errors.

Notice that I'm using `sudo systemctl (start/stop/restart/status)` apache2 to manage my Apache server.

Comment: The `apachectl` command parses the `envvars` file.  If you start Apache directly using `httpd` I think it does not process that file.  Please confirm your startup.  It all depends how your `systemctl` entry is configured for apache2.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, 

I'm quite sure I'm using **apachectl**.

Apache version **2.4.41**

and the `envvars` file  is directly located under the `$APACHE_ROOT`, there is no `bin/` directory.